# Auto-complete values should appear based on the value selected in another text box

Tags: php, jquery

Can anybody please help me on this? I tried of do this in many ways but I couldn’t.

Basically in my web page, I have one drop down box (country) and one auto-complete list(state). 
In the country drop down box, I have two values ("India" and "US"). And state auto-complete list contains 6 values ("Delhi","Assam","Tamil Nadu","Alabama","Alaska","Florida").
So here comes my requirement, For example, **if user selects "India" in the country text box, then, only the** 
**Indian states ("Delhi","Assam","Tamil Nadu") should be visible or available for him to select in the auto-complete list** 
**and the US states should not be visible to the user.**
similarly when the user selects US in the country drop down text box, then only the us states should be available in the state auto-complete list for user to select.

Can some only please help me with a sample piece of code.....

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <script>
          $(function() {
            var collegetypes = [
              "Delhi",
              "Assam",
              "Tamil Nadu",
              "Alabama",
              "Alaska",
              "Florida"
            ];
            $( "#istate" ).autocomplete({
              source: collegetypes
            });
          });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $country = ( !empty( $_REQUEST['COUNTRY'] ) ? $_REQUEST['COUNTRY'] : null );
        $state = ( !empty( $_REQUEST['STATE'] ) ? $_REQUEST['STATE'] : null );

    ?>
        Ajax load<BR>
            <form id="myForm" action='test1.php' method='GET' rel="history">
                Country <BR>
                <select name="COUNTRY"  value="<?=$country;?>">
                <option value="India" <?= ($country === 'India' ? 'selected="selected"' : '')?> >India</option>
                <option value="US" <?= ($country === 'US' ? 'selected="selected"' : '')?> >US</option>
                </select><BR> <BR>
                State <BR>
                <input type="text" name="STATE" id="istate" value="<?=$state;?>"> <BR> <BR>
                <input id="sub" type="submit" value="Search" align="centre"/>
            </form>

            <!--other part of code!-->
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You need to use ajax to fetch only those states where countryid matches the country selected. You donot seem to have any tables for this. You can user arrays then

Comment: Add an event listener to the country selector. When the country changes, you need to filter the list of colleges to only those in the chosen country and tell autocomplete that those are the only valid options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

HTML

```
<form id="myForm" action='test1.php' method='GET' rel="history">
    Country <BR>
    <select name="COUNTRY"  id="country" >
    <option value="India" >India</option>
    <option value="US">US</option>
    </select><BR> <BR>
    State <BR>
    <input type="text" name="STATE" id="istate" value=""> <BR> <BR>
    <input id="sub" type="submit" value="Search" align="centre"/>
</form>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    var collegetypesIndia = [
        "Delhi",
        "Assam",
        "Tamil Nadu"
    ];
    var collegetypesUS = [

        "Alabama",
        "Alaska",
        "Florida"
    ];
    $('#country').change(function(){
        if( $('#country').val() == 'India' )
        {
            $( "#istate" ).autocomplete({'source':collegetypesIndia});
        }
        else
        {
            $( "#istate" ).autocomplete({'source':collegetypesUS});
        }
    }); 
    $('#country').change();   
});
```

check it out at:
http://jsfiddle.net/GM6Fk/1/